# Unable to logout via an ajax request in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.1 and I am trying to setup a simple login/logout system. I can easily login using:

```
Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]);
```

But if I try to logout via an ajax request using `Auth::logout();`, it does not log out the user. Manually going to the logout route in a browser tab however works just fine.

**note:** if my controller looks like this:

```
public function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();

    dd(Auth::user());
}
```

Then the request returns `null`. This should indicate the user has been logged out, but if I pass another request - I am still logged in.

**Edit**

Ajax call:

```
import request from 'superagent'

    request.get(env.api + endpoint)
        .withCredentials()
        .set({
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        })
        .end((err, res) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve(res.body);
        })
```

**EDIT**

I found the source of my problem. It was a single route that looked like this:

`Route::get('image/users/{image}', ['as' => 'fetch.users.images', 'uses' => 'Files@fetchUserImage']);`

Changing the route path `image/users/{image}` solved my problem. Still curious as to why this caused an error with Auth? The route was not interfering with any of my other routes.

**Edit**

My above edit was wrong. It is to do with that route but its not the naming.

I am requesting an image from the route `Route::get('image/users/{image}', ['as' => 'fetch.users.images', 'uses' => 'Files@fetchUserImage']);` whose associated controller looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Storage;

class Files extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('basic');
    }

    public function fetchUserImage($image)
    {
        $image = 'users/images/' . $image;
        if (Storage::disk('s3')->exists($image)) {
            return response(Storage::disk('s3')->get($image), 200, ['Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg']);
        } else {
            return response('Image not found', 404);
        }
    }
}
```

I am requesting the image with JS like this:

```
let img = new Image();
img.onload = () => this.state.update ? this.setState({image: props.src}) : null;
img.src = this.props.src;
```

When Laravel returns `404` or `false` or anything that isn't an image, the JS sends the request again. After I logout, Laravel still has an image request to process and the `response('Image not found', 404)` gets triggered `after` my logout succeeds and then as the `response` contains the logged in session info, my browser gets indirectly logged back in.

Haven't come up with a fix for this yet. Not sure how to go about it.

Comment: you just need to loose a session via an ajax call, and it should log you out.

Comment: I have tried `Session::flush()` and that did not work. Is that what you mean by loose a session?

Comment: What is session:flush, you should be using session_unset

Comment: No, `Session::flush()` clears the systems sessions. But in any case that has nothing to do with my updated question.